# $dx/dt=rx-\ln(1+x)$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems

I have the equation $\frac{dx}{dt}=rx-\ln(1+x)$
I know the bifurcation point is at $r=1$ but I saw this through the geometric approach. How would I get this from a purely algebraic method?

Comment: What do you count as "purely algebraic" method?  There isn't really an "algebraic" method of solving for $x$ in $rx-\log(1+x)=0$.

Comment: I mean is there a way to see it without having to draw the graphs

Answer (score 1):

There is always a root of $f\colon x\in(-1,\infty)\mapsto rx-\log(1+x)$ at $x=0$.  Since $f$ is convex, and $\lim_{x\to -1}f(x)=\lim_{x\to+\infty}f(x)=+\infty$, there is one other root unless the horizontal line is the support line of $f$, i.e., $f'(0)=0$, which is the same as saying $r=1$.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of $$rx-\log(1+x)=0$$ is
$$x=-1-\frac{1}{r}W\left(-e^{-r} r\right)$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.

In the real domain, $W(t)$ exists if $t \geq -\frac 1e$ and then the result.